# How do I upgrade an ink contract with storage changes?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, storage, contracts

Let's say I have a simple/contrived ink contract:

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}
```

Now let's say it's in production and `a == 1` and `b == 2`.

I've done some work and realised that I no longer need `a` and instead need a new variable in storage, `c`.

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
}
```

I've compiled the contract and done a `set_code_hash()` on my production contract. I've also set the `c` variable to `3`.

I now no longer need `a` in my contract storage, so I remove it. Here's where the problem lies. The contract storage is currently laid out like so:

```
[1,2,3]
 ^ ^ ^
 a b c
```

Removing the `a` field like so:

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
}
```

and doing a `set_code_hash()` leaves the underlying storage unchanged, but the fields shift like so:

```
[1,2,3]
 ^ ^ 
 b c
```

Which is rather frustrating. How can I remove the `a` variable from the storage too? Something to make the storage become:

```
[2,3]
 ^ ^ 
 b c
```

I've contemplated doing some kind of bit shift on the contract storage by the size of the field being removed, but I have no idea where to start accessing the `byte[]` for the contract storage!

Further, imagine using complex types where the fields being removed are not at the start. How could that be done?
E.g.

```
#[ink(storage)
pub struct MyContract {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
    d: Mapping<AccountId, AccountId>, // <-- let's say I want to remove this field
    e: Vec<u8>,
    f: u128,
    g: Mapping<u8, u8>,
}
```

Comment: @HCastano we spoke briefly about this at the polkadot decoded conference, what are your thoughts? I've tried setting the storage key (e.g. `pub struct MyContract<KEY: StorageKey = ManualKey<0xABCDEF01>>`) but that maintains the storage pointing to the same place all the time, not dealing with any migration of the storage data itself. Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not change the layout of the storage after upgrade. The order and types of the fields has to remain the same. If you want to remove the field `a`, you can simply rename it to `c` as the order will still be `u8, u8`.

You can read more about upgrading storage in ink! [here](https://use.ink/basics/upgradeable-contracts#storage-compatibility)

Comment: Sure, that would work for the example I gave. But in the real world things change and contract storage is included in that. I've read the docs about upgrading storage in ink already.

Comment: How would you tackle this with the more complex case of changing variable types (e.g. u8 to u16) or removing fields entirely?